# Laço de repetição em assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

Como posso fazer uma repetição um determinado número de vezes em assembly (no [MIPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture))?

Exemplo em pseudocódigo, supondo que a variável `registrador` seja um registrador que eu quero que receba todos os números de 1 a 6 (um por vez, obviamente)

```
var i = 1;
while(i <= 6)
{
    registrador = i;
    i = i + 1;
}
```

Comment: O que é este `registrador`?

Comment: É pra ser um registrador do processador, eu quero que no final do código ele tenha o valor 6 (como no código apresentado). Como eu consigo executar passo a passo, posso ver os valores sendo alterados.

Comment: Não manjo nada de MIPS, mas seria algo assim: https://godbolt.org/g/Nlcax8

Comment: Eu também não, @bigown Mas esse código tá horrível :p

Comment: Culpa do GCC, não minha :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algo assim?

[Referência de instruções do MIPS.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#Jump_and_branch)

```
.globl main

 main:
    li $v0, 0               # registrador
    li $t0, 1               # valor inicial do índice do laço

loop:
    bgt $t0, 5, exit        # se $t0 > 5, interrompa laço
    move $v0, $t0           # registrador = $t0
    addiu $t0, $t0, 1       # incrementa índice
    j loop                  # vá para o label [loop:]

exit:
```

Comment: Que compilador horrível que é o GCC pra MIPS. Eu tava até achando o Assembly dele muito prolixo.

Comment: @bigown para diminuir a frustração, lembre-se: Sempre existem piores. ;)

Comment: @jbueno referencia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#Jump_and_branch

Answer (score 3):

Fiz uma versão um pouco mais simples que a da outra resposta. Sem usar o `move` - eu mudei de ideia logo depois.

```
main:
    li $t0, 0             # $t0 é o incrementador (o "i" da pergunta)
    li $t1, 6             # $t1 é o valor máximo (serão 5 loops)

loop: 
    beq $t0, $t1, done    # se o $t0 for igual a $t1, vai para 'done' (acabou o loop)
    addi $t0, $t0, 1      # incrementar $t0 em 1
    j loop                # pular para (goto) 'while'

done:
```

Answer (score 0):

program simq1;
uses crt;
var i,k:integer;
    vet:array [1..10] of integer;

begin
     clrscr;
     writeln('Quais os 10 numeros?');
     for i:=1 to 10 do
     begin
          readln(vet[i]);
     end;
     for i:=1 to 10 do
     begin
          for k:=1 to 10 do
          begin
               if (i<>k) and (vet[i]=vet[k]) and (vet[k]<>-1) then
               begin
                    vet[k]:=-1;
                    k:=10;
               end;
          end;
     end;
     writeln('O vetor sem repeticao é');
     for i:=1 to 10 do
     begin
          if vet[i]<>-1 then
          begin
               writeln(vet[i]);
          end;
     end;
     readkey;
end.